# I'm trying to embed the twitter widget with the standard code in cordova, but somehow it only creates the link instead of the widget

Tags: cordova, twitter, ionic-framework

I'm trying to embed the widget in my phonegap/cordova app with the standard code:

```
<a class="twitter-timeline" href="https://twitter.com/Elevraadet_OG" data-widget-id="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" data-chrome="noheader nofooter transparent noscrollbar" data-tweet-limit="16">Tweets af @Elevraadet_OG</a>
<script>
    !function(d,s,id){
        var js,
            fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
            p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';
        if(!d.getElementById(id))
        {
            js=d.createElement(s);
            js.id=id;
            js.src=p+"://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";
            fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);
        }
     }(document,"script","twitter-wjs");
</script>
```

How ever this only creates the Tweets af @Elevraadet_OG link instead of the widget, how come this doesn't work?

Comment: Did you get it to work? I am doing some research myself and nobody seems to have "final" working instructions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So far I found there is a domain issue with cordova + twitter feed. There is a long discussion going on here [Embedded Timelines in a PhoneGap application](https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/11360)

Few solutions are suggested in that link. You can try them. And there is a way around using inAppBrowser using this plugin [Twitter Timeline in PhoneGap application](https://github.com/k-rudy/phonegap-twitter-timeline)